# WordPress shortcode function has some error with code?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have problem with this code down.
Some characters breaking my WordPress website, I am not sure which, I don't know php or coding so much.

```
function check_member( $atts, $content = null )
    {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :
            return $content;
        else :
            $return .= '<img class="background-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="850" height="478" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />';
            $return .= '<img class="logo-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="188" height="50" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; margin: auto;" />';
            $return .= '<h2 style="position: absolute; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; font-size: 1.5rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 10%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">NOT OKAY</h2>';
            $return .= '<p style="position: absolute; margin: 0; font-size: 1.2rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">SORRY, YOU ARE NOT MEMBER</p>';
        endif;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is giving you a warning on your page, likely it is because of your first line. Since you don't declare `$return` anywhere, you can not use `.=`, but rather `=`:

```
$return = '<img class="background-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="850" height="478" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />';
```

Secondly, you don't need to concatenate like that, each line does not have to be separated broken into it's own statement:

```
$return = '<img class="background-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="850" height="478" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
<img class="logo-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="188" height="50" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; margin: auto;" />
<h2 style="position: absolute; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; font-size: 1.5rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 10%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">NOT OKAY</h2>
<p style="position: absolute; margin: 0; font-size: 1.2rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">SORRY, YOU ARE NOT MEMBER</p>';
```

Thirdly, you are not returning this variable so nothing will happen when it hits the latter half of the script. You need to return it:

```
$return = '<img class="background-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="850" height="478" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
<img class="logo-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="188" height="50" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; margin: auto;" />
<h2 style="position: absolute; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; font-size: 1.5rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 10%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">NOT OKAY</h2>
<p style="position: absolute; margin: 0; font-size: 1.2rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">SORRY, YOU ARE NOT MEMBER</p>';

// This will send it back to use via echo
return $return;
```

Forth, your `$atts` in not being used, there is no point having it. It's probably messing your code up as well.

### NON-SHORTCODE

If you are not doing a `[shortcode]`, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
function check_member($content = null )
    {
        if (is_user_logged_in())
            return $content;

        ob_start();
        ?>
        <img class="background-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="850" height="478" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
        <img class="logo-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="188" height="50" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; margin: auto;" />
        <h2 style="position: absolute; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; font-size: 1.5rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 10%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">NOT OKAY</h2>
        <p style="position: absolute; margin: 0; font-size: 1.2rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">SORRY, YOU ARE NOT MEMBER</p>
        <?php
        $content    =   ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $content;
    }
```

**To use:**

```
$whatever = 'Some sort of text that will be written if logged in.';
echo check_member($whatever);
```

### SHORTCODE

If you are wanting to do a `[shortcode]`, you will probably be looking to do this:

```
function check_member($attr)
    {
        $settings['content']    =   false;
        $a                      =   shortcode_atts($settings,$attr,'checkmember');

        if (is_user_logged_in())
            return $a['content'];

        ob_start();
        ?>
        <img class="background-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="850" height="478" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />
        <img class="logo-img" src="website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="188" height="50" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; margin: auto;" />
        <h2 style="position: absolute; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; font-size: 1.5rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 10%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">NOT OKAY</h2>
        <p style="position: absolute; margin: 0; font-size: 1.2rem; color: white; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0%; margin: auto; padding: 50px;">SORRY, YOU ARE NOT MEMBER</p>
        <?php
        $content    =   ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $content;
    }

add_shortcode('checkmember','check_member');
```